# Дескриптор данных

Tags: python

Необходимо описать класс-дескриптор, который хранит в себе произвольные значения. Этот класс должен содержать метод `null()`, который будет "обнулять" все ранее сохраненные значения. Загвоздка в том, как мне получить ссылки на все объекты-владельцы этого дескриптора.

```
class Nuller(object):
 
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = value
 
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
 
    def __delete__(self, value):
        del self.value
 
    def null():
        print('reset')
 
 
class Team:
    score = Nuller()
 
team1 = Team()
team2 = Team()
team1.score = 5   #5
team2.score = 28   #28
Nuller.null()
print(team1, team2)  #0 0
```

Comment: Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос, то это противоречит принципам ООП, вообще конечно сложно судить о реализации не зная задачи, но на данный момент не вижу проблемы использовать обычную БД

Comment: @T1bon Нельзя обнулить **все** ранее сохраненные (когда-либо записанные в одну переменную) значения. Можно "обнулить" последнее значение, которое записано в конкретную переменную (в терминах Python - связано с определенным именем):  self.value = nil  и или self.value = 0.  Python это язык со сборкой мусора и ты не должен думать о памяти, которой ты никак не управляешь. Все прошлые значения переменной автоматически уничтожаются сборщиком мусора, если на них никто больше не ссылается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем в класс `Nuller` множество, в котором будем хранить объекты и названия полей, которые нужно обнулить. При записи чего-то в поле (вызов метода `__set__`) добавляем объект и имя поля в это множество. При вызове метода `null` проходим это множество и обнуляем значения записанных полей в записанных объектах.

Также обратите внимание, что запись/получение данных идет через
`instance` (в данном случае это будут объекта класса `Team`), а не через `self` (объект класса `Nuller`), т.к. объект `Nuller` создается один раз при создании поля класса, в итоге будет один объект `Nuller` на все объекты `Team` (в вашем примере из вопроса после `team1.score = 5` все объекты класса `Team` будут в `score` показывать 5, а после `team2.score = 28` - будут показывать 28).

```
class Nuller(object):
    instances_and_attributes = set()
    
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        # Значения фактически будут записываться в поле с добавлением подчеркивания
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # Добавляем объект и приватное имя поля в список обнуления
        # (если обнулять по публичному имени поля, то вызов метода __set__ зациклится)
        self.instances_and_attributes.add((instance, self.private_name))
        setattr(instance, self.private_name, value)
 
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr(instance, self.private_name)
    
    def __delete__(self, instance):
        delattr(instance, self.private_name)

    def null():
        print('reset')
        for instance, name in Nuller.instances_and_attributes:
            setattr(instance, name, 0)


class Team:
    score = Nuller()


team1 = Team()
team2 = Team()

team1.score = 5
team2.score = 28

print(team1.score, team2.score)  # 5 28
Nuller.null()
print(team1.score, team2.score)  # 0 0
```

Comment: Отлично, но из множества instances_and_attributes тоже нужно удалить ссылки на все объекты-владельцы, иначе если, удалить один из объектов, а затем его "обнулить" метод отработает, а такого не должно быть.

Comment: @T1bon, я не вижу проблем, в том чтобы метод мог отрабатывать несколько раз. Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос с доступом к атрибутам класса, то можете использовать магический метод `__dict__`:

```
class E():
    def __init__(self):
        self.rod = 10

class Er(E):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        super(Er, self).__init__()
        self.val1 = val1
        self.val2 = val2

    def x2_val1(self):
        self.val1 = self.val1 * 2

    def null(self):
        for key in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[key] = 0

obj = Er(4, 5)

obj.null()
print(obj.val1)  # выведет 0
print(obj.rod)   # выведет 0
```